# How to redirect to another link Using href tag laravel 4.2

Tags: redirect, laravel-4, http-redirect

I am very new to laravel and badly struck in a problem. I am trying to to redirect the my laravel web application to on external link through the `href` tag but it does not removed the previous url. Can you guys please tell me where i am doing mistake so that I can solve this issue...
Here is the code

```
<a target="_blank"href="URL{{<?php echo $pick_data['links']->facebook; ?>}}">     
   Facebook
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
<a href="{{ $pick_data['links']->facebook }}" >Go to Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `url()` function works for routes in your application, not external URL's.

I would put the content of the url in a view variable as such:

```
$links = new \stdClass();
$links->facebook = 'https://facebook.com';

return view('main', [
        'pickdata' => ['links' => $links]
]);
```

And retrieve it in `main.blade.php`

```
{{$pickdata['links']->facebook}}
```